# What are the earliest advocates for animal rights and/or moral equivalency between killing animals Vs. Killing humans?

Tags: ethics, history-of-philosophy, animals, veganism

The vegans make arguments that killing sentient animals is murder in the same way that it would be to kill a human. They argue that the distinction is arbitrary, and from a very rationalist, reductionist point of view, they make a compelling argument.

What are the earliest philosophers (preferably but not necessarily enlightenment type figures) to grapple with the basis of this distinction, whether they concluded in favour of it (and so in favour of eating meat), or concluded against recognising any distinction between killing humans and animals (essentially the modern vegan position)?

Comment: I don't think I've met even one single vegan who's argued for "moral equivalency between killing animals vs killing humans" or who's said "the distinction is arbitrary" . There's the idea that [there isn't a trait](https://philosophicalvegan.com/wiki/index.php/NameTheTrait) that rationally morally separates humans from other animals, but vegans mostly just use that idea to argue that animals have at least some moral worth, such that it's immoral to force them to live in torturous conditions and kill them because you like how their flesh tastes.

Comment: Daniel in the [Bible](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel%201&version=NIV). Pythagoras, also the post vedic Hindus, along with Jains and Buddhists, [Zarathustra](https://www.ivu.org/history/east/zoroaster.html) (the original, not Nietzsche's fictionalized account) See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_vegetarianism

Comment: This paper asks the same question: Animal Rights -'One-of-Us-ness': From the Greek Philosophy towards a Modern ... https://philarchive.org/archive/CHAARO-7

Answer (score -2):

I see it this way...

- there are 33 billion chickens globally, currently.
- we currently kill and eat over 70 million chickens per year.
- very few vegans would adopt pet chickens
- without the egg and chicken meat industry, there would be almost no chickens globally.

The same goes for cows and pigs and sheep and goats... animals that have life, because we want them to, and which would not have life, if we did not give them life so we could take it later.

There is a lot of life existing singularly because some meat-eaters are paying for it to exist.

---

To understand the difference between a bright and aware animal, and one that, erm, "ain't so much so"... consider this as a tell...

For a couple of years, my path walking to work was shortened if I cut a corner using some train tracks for a few hundred yards.  Looked just like these.

[image]

The winter months provided great opportunity to observe and analyze the tracks of many animals, over many samples.

There was a lone coyote, that almost every day would leave a single trail of tracks going up the middle of the rails, then back again, the entire length that I walked almost to the road where I turned off.

One day when the snow was the just the right depth that the rails were level with the top of the snow, the coyote actually walked on the rails, for a couple of hundred yards, dead straight because of being on the rail.  (a couple of slips, here and there).  And the same in the opposite direction on the other rail.

Turkeys, wild, many... would leave trails... their trails go in almost completely random big looping dipsy doodling curves.  Turkeys never go with intent and purpose.... or barely any.  The eat where they happenstance to end up.  They are truly, truly, stupid stupid animals.

Like chickens.

The coyote, on the other hand... actually quite wiley.

IT would be cruel to restrictively confine a coyote.  You would drive it nuts.  Chickens don't know they are confined.

Chickens and coyotes should be treated differently.  Not viewed as one and the same when considering needs.

Similarly... chickens, and humans should definitely be viewed differently, when considering "rights" and what constitutes "humane" treatment.

---

None of which says "Treat animals badly".

I just mean, judiciously assess what an animal considers "badly", compared to a life in the wild, the natural alternative.  Or none at all.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152222/discussion-on-answer-by-alistair-riddoch-what-are-the-earliest-advocates-for-ani); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: "*I had created a hierarchy of spirits.*" - from the book "The Tracker", I think, by Tom Brown Jr.